# Calculation (adding) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Values from different columns are required to be added with 10 marks each if there value is 1.
The accumulated result is required to be summed up in a column of a table. However, the sum should not exceed 20 marks. Thus, if the sum comes to 30, the result in column would always be 20.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN paint.is_weak  = 1 
            THEN 10 
        ELSE 0
    END
        +
    CASE
        WHEN paint.is_low  = 1 
            THEN 10 
        ELSE 0
    END
        +
    CASE
        WHEN paint.is_hi = 'red'
            THEN 10 
        ELSE 0
    END
from PAINT;
```

How will i ensure that the sum should not exceed 20 and is there any possibility of having a variable defined in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
select least(((is_weak = 1) + (is_low = 1) + (is_hi = 1)) * 10, 20)
from paint
```

And BTW yes, you can have variables in MySQL. You can define one directly in a query with a subquery like this

```
select t.*, @your_var := @your_var + 1
from your_table t
cross join (select @your_var := 0) v
```

Comment: one of the value is varchar

Comment: That does not matter. MySQL makes an auto cast to number to make the comparision with `1`.